# Why are there two byte sizes for timestamps in the Bitcoin protocol?

Tags: protocol

Reading [*Block Headers*](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#Block_Headers) on the Bitcoin wiki, I learned that the timestamp in a block header is four bytes, and the timestamp in the "version" message is eight bytes. Why are there two sizes, and why isn't it more consistent?

[image]

Comment: This is actually a good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was discussed in the mailing list a while back:
http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=30824341

I'm guessing 32-bit timestamp was used by Satoshi in the original client and the 64-bit timestamp was introduced later to avoid timestamp overflow.

We may need to change (hardfork) the old 32-bit timestamp fields to 64-bit at some point. See https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Hardfork_Wishlist